# Marhsal/Unmarshal Request to Java Object to Response

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, google-apps

Is there a library that can convert an HttpServletRequest to a Java object representation of the payload and then convert the Java object back into an HttpServletResponse?

So far I've looked at:

**Jsoup**: I didn't see any way to convert CSS and JavaScript and I didn't see any way to convert from/to an HttpServletRequest/HttpServletResponse.

**GWT**: I didn't see a way to use different `onModuleLoad()` methods per custom URL. I also found it confusing when trying to merge it with servlets because you don't actually submit any forms with it, you just use ajax calls.